# Check for string in several Enums with a switch statement

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I have a listbox that could be filled with values from one of two enums, or both of them. Basically this code:

```
public enum NamesA { Adam , Albert }
public enum NamesB { Bert , Bob }
```

and later

```
List<string> nameList = new List<string>();

if (reason) nameList.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(NamesA)));
else if (reason) nameList.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(NamesB)));
else
{
    nameList.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(NamesA)));
    nameList.AddRange(Enum.GetNames(typeof(NamesB)));
}

foreach (string name in nameList)
    listBox1.Items.Add(name);
```

My problem is that later in the code I want different things to happen depending on the users choice in the listbox.

I know I can check it like this:

```
string chosenName = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

if (chosenName.Equals(NamesA.Adam.ToString()))
{ /*some stuff happens*/ }
else if (chosenName.Equals(NamesB.Bob.ToString()))
{ /*other stuff happens*/ }
/* ...and so on */
```

...but I would prefer using a Switch.
I can't find a way for it to work. Anyone have an idea?

---

EDIT: I should also say that there has to be room for the switch to handle future NamesC, ...D, ...E, etc. enums.

Comment: `switch(chosenName) { case NamesA.Adam.ToString (): //logic  break; ....}`

Comment: `NamesA.Adam.ToString ()` isn't a constant expression to be valid for a case statement.

Comment: Please check my solution. I hope it will suffice your requirement.

Comment: Ooh yeah..my bad. Missed that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to leverage the integer which is the underlying data type of any enum. Have a look at how I've achieved it:

File: CustomListItem.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public class CustomListItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int EnumValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

File: Form1.cs

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public enum NamesA { Adam = 0, Albert = 1 };
    public enum NamesB { Bert = 2, Bob = 3 }

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List <CustomListItem> nameList = new List<CustomListItem>();
            int reason = 1;
            if (reason == 1)
                foreach (NamesA item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NamesA)))
                    nameList.Add(new CustomListItem { Text = item.ToString(), EnumValue = (int)item });
            else if (reason == 2)
            {
                foreach (NamesB item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NamesB)))
                    nameList.Add(new CustomListItem { Text = item.ToString(), EnumValue = (int)item });
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (NamesA item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NamesA)))
                    nameList.Add(new CustomListItem { Text = item.ToString(), EnumValue = (int)item });
                foreach (NamesB item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(NamesB)))
                nameList.Add(new CustomListItem { Text = item.ToString(), EnumValue = (int)item });
            }
            listBox1.DataSource = nameList;
            listBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
            listBox1.ValueMember = "EnumValue";

        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int chosenNameEnumValue = (int) listBox1.SelectedValue;

            switch (chosenNameEnumValue)
            {
                case (int) NamesA.Adam:
                    /*some stuff happens*/
                    break;
                case (int) NamesA.Albert:
                    /*other stuff happens*/
                    break;
                case (int)NamesB.Bert:
                    /*some stuff happens*/
                    break;
                case (int)NamesB.Bob:
                    /*other stuff happens*/
                    break;
                default:
                    /* ...and so on */
                    break;
            }
        }
}
}
```

Comment: That's a nice solution. Thanks!